# how to restart clickpad evdev driver

Tags: drivers, restart, evdev

I am running a variant of evdev for the purpose of wheel emulation scrolling using the TrackPoint and clickpad on a modern ThinkPad. The driver works well but the scrolling emulation stops working after a suspend event. In order to try to have it working after resuming (rather than having to reboot the computer), how can I restart evdev?

The driver (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xf86-input-evdev-trackpoint/) for Arch was created by Taegil Bae (esrevinu) (https://bitbucket.org/esrevinu/xf86-input-evdev-trackpoint) and a procedure (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/1246683/comments/40) was described by dalcde (https://launchpad.net/~dalcde) for packaging the driver for Ubuntu and updating. The procedure is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

wget https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xf/xf86-input-evdev-trackpoint/xf86-input-evdev-trackpoint.tar.gz
tar -xzf xf86-input-evdev-trackpoint.tar.gz
git clone git://git.debian.org/git/pkg-xorg/driver/xserver-xorg-input-evdev
git clone git://git.debian.org/git/pkg-xorg/driver/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

mv xf86-input-evdev-trackpoint arch
mv xserver-xorg-input-evdev evdev
mv xserver-xorg-input-synaptics synaptics

cp synaptics/src/{eventcomm.c,eventcomm.h,properties.c,synaptics.c,synapticsstr.h,synproto.c,synproto.h} evdev/src
cp synaptics/include/synaptics-properties.h evdev/src
cp arch/*.patch evdev

cd evdev
patch -p1 -i 0001-implement-trackpoint-wheel-emulation.patch
patch -p1 -i 0008-disable-clickpad_guess_clickfingers.patch
patch -p1 -i 0010-add-synatics-files-into-Makefile.am.patch

dpkg-buildpackage

cd ..
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-input-evdev_*.deb
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
sudo cp arch/90-evdev-trackpoint.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```